# get data from newsapi

Tags: android, getmethod, newsapi

I'm trying to get news API from https://newsapi.org.
on IntelliJ when I call : httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET"); I get response and its working but on the androidstudio when I call the method I get this error : java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://newsapi.org

here is the full code:

```
`  try {
        URL url = new URL("https://newsapi.org");
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpURLConnection.connect();

        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        String s = bufferedReader.readLine();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        while (s != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(s);
            s = bufferedReader.readLine();
        }

        System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  `
```

here is the full code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mA m = new mA();
    m.execute();
}

class mA extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?q=Apple&from=2022-08-31&sortBy=popularity&apiKey=648805f67bdb4aa6a454d4f6480ae35d");
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpURLConnection.connect();

            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String s = bufferedReader.readLine();
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while (s != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(s);
                s = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("articles");
            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
            String sss = jsonObject1.getString("title");


            System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {


        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }
}
```

}

and the log:
2022-09-02 03:11:15.329 21717-21758/th.o.th.newstest02 I/AdrenoGLES: Build Config                     : S L 8.0.11 AArch64
2022-09-02 03:11:15.375 21717-21758/th.o.th.newstest02 I/AdrenoGLES: PFP: 0x005ff112, ME: 0x005ff066
2022-09-02 03:11:15.386 21717-21758/th.o.th.newstest02 W/AdrenoUtils: <ReadGpuID_from_sysfs:194>: Failed to open /sys/class/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/gpu_model
2022-09-02 03:11:15.386 21717-21758/th.o.th.newstest02 W/AdrenoUtils: ReadGpuID:218: Failed to read chip ID from gpu_model. Fallback to use the GSL path
2022-09-02 03:11:15.375 21717-21717/th.o.th.newstest02 W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:12012): avc: denied { search } for name="kgsl-3d0" dev="sysfs" ino=29187 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c88,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs_kgsl:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2022-09-02 03:11:15.436 21717-21758/th.o.th.newstest02 W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
2022-09-02 03:11:22.310 21717-21762/th.o.th.newstest02 W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?q=Apple&from=2022-08-31&sortBy=popularity&apiKey=648805f67bdb4aa6a454d4f6480ae35d
2022-09-02 03:11:22.311 21717-21762/th.o.th.newstest02 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:255)
2022-09-02 03:11:22.311 21717-21762/th.o.th.newstest02 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:211)
2022-09-02 03:11:22.312 21717-21762/th.o.th.newstest02 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
2022-09-02 03:11:22.312 21717-21762/th.o.th.newstest02 W/System.err:     at th.o.th.newstest02.MainActivity$mA.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:41)
2022-09-02 03:11:22.313 21717-21762/th.o.th.newstest02 W/System.err:     at th.o.th.newstest02.MainActivity$mA.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:30)
2022-09-02 03:11:22.313 21717-21762/th.o.th.newstest02 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:378)
2022-09-02 03:11:22.313 21717-21762/th.o.th.newstest02 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2022-09-02 03:11:22.313 21717-21762/th.o.th.newstest02 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:289)
2022-09-02 03:11:22.314 21717-21762/th.o.th.newstest02 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2022-09-02 03:11:22.314 21717-21762/th.o.th.newstest02 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2022-09-02 03:11:22.314 21717-21762/th.o.th.newstest02 W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
2022-09-02 03:13:17.211 21717-21732/th.o.th.newstest02 W/System: A resource failed to call end.

Comment: INTERNET permission requested in Manifest file?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> I have it

Comment: Dose the newsapi.org have any limits on the requests? i mean maybe there is a limit for android requests.

Answer (score 0):

By calling the base URL (https://newsapi.org) with the `GET` method you will fetch the website content in HTML. It's just like opening the URL in your browser.

[image: Postman API call]

According to the [Documentation](https://newsapi.org/docs/get-started), you should first get an API key to be able to send requests and fetch the news. Aside from this, you should use the correct API address mentioned [here](https://newsapi.org/docs/endpoints).

Comment: i have the url via api key but stiil the same issue :https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?q=Apple&from=2022-08-31&sortBy=popularity&apiKey=648805f67bdb4aa6a454d4f6480ae35d

Comment: I just tested the URL you sent. It's ok in postman. The problem should be somewhere else. Could you please share the complete code and also Logcat stacktrace?

Comment: I add the full code in question

Comment: I checked your code. The problem is that the API returning status code 403. Check this [gist](https://gist.github.com/dferreira-cvl/50697a479ebdb331b2e8a7ead2c8f4b5#file-httpurlconnection-get-java-L10) out and see how to check the status code before reading the input stream. If the status code is not 200, you should get the **`errorStream`** instead of **`inputStream`** to see the error.

Comment: By the way, I highly recommend using [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) for API calls, and also [Coroutine](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-overview.html) for background tasks. The AsyncTask is already deprecated. Check out [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/retrofit-with-kotlin-coroutine-in-android/) and [this](https://blog.mindorks.com/using-retrofit-with-kotlin-coroutines-in-android)

Comment: thanks for the response ill inform you if that works.